# google.cloud.vision_v1.types.image_annotator.AnnotateImageResponse to Json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-vision

I am using Google Vision `document_text_detection` function and I am trying to dump the AnnotateImageResponse to json

Earlier this code used to word

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.Image(content=image)

response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
texts = MessageToDict(response)
text_json = json.dumps(texts)
```

Now it throws this error `AttributeError: 'DESCRIPTOR'`

I tried all the responses in other answers but none of them worked. I also tried `protobuf3-to-dict` but it also throws error

```
from protobuf_to_dict import protobuf_to_dict
text_json = protobuf_to_dict(response)
```

It throws:

```
AttributeError: 'ListFields'
```

I know I can iterate it the object but I need to dump it in json file to maintain cache.

Answer (score 5):

Found a better answer on the GitHub thread I was following, [posted yesterday](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/70#issuecomment-712992731). Translated for this question:

```
import proto
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.Image(content=image)

response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
texts = proto.Message.to_json(response)
text_json = json.dumps(texts)
```

If response needed as a dict, do the following instead of json.dumps:

```
mydict = json.loads(texts)
```

All message types are now defined using [proto-plus](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/), which uses different methods for serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem today with the new Google Vision Client (2.0.0) and solved it unpacking the AnnotateImageResponse object. I Don't think this is how the new API should work but at the moment no solution is proposed in the documentation. Try this:

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
image = vision.Image(content=image)

response = client.document_text_detection(image=image)
texts = MessageToDict(response._pb)
text_json = json.dumps(texts)
```

Note the use of response._pb instead of response.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and it works:

```
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import AnnotateImageResponse
json_str = AnnotateImageResponse.to_json(response)
```